# Split a string with multiple unique delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I have string in this format

```
x/1.25 o/33.3 description for item A`
```

Now, I want to split it so it becomes

```
1.25, 33.3, description for item A
```

So far, I used `.split(x/|o/)` which works for this case. However, it becomes invalid if the user put `x/` or `o/` in the `description of item A`, like `description o/ item A`.

Is there any better regex that utilize the order of the parameter and delimiter in above string format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to do

```
String[] fields = input.split("\\s+",3);
```

which will split into 3 blank-delimited fields.  Then apply your regex to only the first two and reassemble the result into the output.

Comment: Thats make sense. Can you combine them in 1 line? I prefer one-line solution, if there is one. Thanks